# Multiple generated popups / forms returning unique download links

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, forms

I've got a page which has a Bootstrap tabsection. Every tab contains a machine (custom post type), which has a unique PDF download link attached to it by an ACF field. When pressed on the button, a modal opens with a form which has ID 1350. When the form has been filled in and sent has been hit, the relevant PDF file is automatically downloaded in a new tab.

The problem here is that when there's multiple machines, both the PDF files start downloaden. When the button on the second machine is pressed, the first machine pdf gets downloaded, then the second one.

I've tried outputting event.detail.containrePostId but it only returns the post id of the first machine in the query, twice. What i can't seem to achieve is that when a button is pressed on the form, only that relevant pdf gets downloaded. Below is the flexible content part that handles the tabsection.

```
<?php elseif( get_row_layout() == 'tabsectie'): ?>


        <div class="section wow padding-0 margt-0 margb-0 animated">
            <div class="tabsection-slider-wrapper">
        <div class="pseudo-bg pseudo-right pseudo-lightblue"></div>

        <?php if( have_rows('tabs_repeater') ): $i = 1; // Set the increment variable ?>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center tabsection-row">
                <div class="col-xl-8">
                        <div class="tab-wrapper">
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">

                                <?php while ( have_rows('tabs_repeater') ) : the_row(); ?>

                                    <?php $machines = get_sub_field('machine'); ?>

                                        <?php if( $machines ): ?>

                                            <?php foreach( $machines as $post ): ?>

                                                <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>

                                                    <li class="nav-item<?php if($i == 1) echo ' active';?>">
                                                        <a class="nav-link<?php if($i == 1) echo ' active';?>" id="<?php echo sanitize_title_with_dashes(get_the_title(get_the_ID())); ?>-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#<?php echo sanitize_title_with_dashes(get_the_title(get_the_ID())); ?>" role="tab" aria-controls="<?php echo sanitize_title_with_dashes(get_the_title(get_the_ID())); ?>" aria-selected="true"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a>
                                                    </li>

                                            <?php endforeach; ?>

                                        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

                                        <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php   $i++; /* Increment the increment variable */ endwhile; //End the loop ?>


                            </ul>
                            </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">

        <?php $i = 1; /* Set the increment variablew */ while ( have_rows('tabs_repeater') ) : the_row(); ?>

        <?php $machines = get_sub_field('machine'); ?>

            <?php if( $machines ): ?>

                <?php foreach( $machines as $post ): ?>

                    <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>

                    <?php 

                    $pdf_machine = get_field('pdf_machine');

                    ?>

                        <div class="tab-pane fade show <?php if($i == 1) echo 'active';?>" id="<?php echo sanitize_title_with_dashes(get_the_title(get_the_ID())); ?>" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="<?php echo sanitize_title_with_dashes(get_the_title(get_the_ID())); ?>-tab">
                            <div class="image-slider-content-wrapper">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-4 offset-lg-2 slider-content-left">
                                            <h1 class="mb-5"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                                            <span class="machine-content"><?php get_template_part('blocks/main-fields'); ?></span>
                                            <?php $pdf_machine = get_field('pdf_machine'); ?>
                                            <?php if(!empty($pdf_machine)): ?>
                                            
                                                <?php var_dump($pdf_machine); ?>

                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#downloadModalMachine-<?php echo $i; ?>">Download brochure</button>

                                                <?php 
                                                
                                                /*pdf_download(get_the_ID());*/

                                                // Modal template part ONLY for the machines modal
                                                include('includes/modal.php');
                                                
                                                printf("
                                                <script>
                                                  document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) { 
                                                    if ( '1350' == event.detail.contactFormId) { 
                                                      
                                                      alert( event.detail.containerPostId );
                                                    } 
                                                  }, false );
                                                </script>", $pdf_machine);
                                                    
                                                ?>
                                            
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="image-slider wow animate__animated animate__fadeInRight" data-wow-offset="100">
                                    <div class="carousel">
                                    <?php $slider = get_sub_field('slider'); ?>
                                    <?php if(have_rows('media')): ?>
                                        <?php while(have_rows('media')): the_row(); ?>
                                            <?php $slider_type = get_sub_field('media_type'); ?>

                                            <div class="slider-item">

                                                <?php if($slider_type == 'image'): ?>
                                                    <?php $image = get_sub_field('image'); ?>
                                                    <?php if( !empty($image) ): ?>
                                                        <img class=" lider-image" src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['gallery']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                                                    <?php endif; ?>

                                                <?php elseif($slider_type == 'video'): ?>
                                                    <?php $video = get_sub_field('video'); ?>
                                                    <?php if (!empty($video) ): ?>
                                                        <div class="embed-container">
                                                            <?php echo $video; ?>
                                                        </div>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            </div>

                                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slider-arrow-wrapper">
                                        <div class="slider-nav">
                                            <div class="nav-button nav-btn-left">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="nav-button nav-btn-right">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

            <?php endforeach; ?>

            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php   $i++; /* Increment the increment variable */ endwhile; //End the loop ?>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

**Here is the javascript that generates the download link**

```
    <?php 

/*pdf_download(get_the_ID());*/

// Modal template part ONLY for the machines modal
include('includes/modal.php');

printf("
<script>
    document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) { 
    if ( '1350' == event.detail.contactFormId) { 
        window.open('%s'); 
    } 
    }, false );
</script>", $pdf_machine);
    
?>

<?php endif; ?>
```